# WebRTC ICE restart cause MediaStream packet loss all the time?

Tags: webrtc

I want restart ICE when the network has been changed, such as: WIFI change to another WIFI. Then, peerconnection.iceConnectionState would be: checking... connected... complete. But packet lost would be increasing all the time?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uk8H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ybBo.png)

Comment: WebRTC will automatically start sending new candidates that you have to send over your prearranged signaling on network change if needed.

Comment: I restart ICE by `peerconnection.createOff({iceRestart:true},function(offer){},function(err){})`, peerconnection.iceConnectionState would be connected, but we can that packet lost would be increasing all the time by the se second image.